# How can I auto include whole Freemarker template package in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, freemarker

I have `layout.ftl` file auto include configured in `application.properties` like this:

```
spring.freemarker.settings.auto_include = macro/layout.ftl
```

That works fine, however now I'm adding more and more macros in the `macro` package, so my configuration is slowly getting flooded like this:

```
spring.freemarker.settings.auto_include = macro/layout.ftl, macro/macro1.ftl, macro/macro2.ftl, macro/macro3.ftl, macro/macro4.ftl
```

Is it possible to auto include whole `macro` package at once? I tried:

```
spring.freemarker.settings.auto_include = macro
spring.freemarker.settings.auto_include = macro/
spring.freemarker.settings.auto_include = macro/*
spring.freemarker.settings.auto_include = macro/*.ftl
```

None of these seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not out of the box, because the `TemplateLoader` interface (which is what Spring and others implement to load the templates from somewhere) has no directory listing functionality, so core FreeMarker functionality can't do that.

If you can configure FreeMarker from Java code, then you can assemble the list of file names dynamically, and then give it to `Configuration.setAutoIncludes(List templateNames)`. At least with some Spring Boot components it's possible to hook in your own setup code after the properties from the `application.properties` were applied, but I haven't checked if that's so with the FreeMarker Spring Boot feature too.